# Apache Tomcat configuration: Access not authorized

Tags: java, tomcat

I am using Apache Tomcat server. I installed successfully on my computer because the server in running but My problem is that I cannot open a page due wrong credential. Below is the message after  I enter my credential as username: `root` and password: `tomcat`

```
Access to Tomcat server has not been authorized. Set the correct username 
and password with the "manager-script" role in the Tomcat customizer in the 
Server Manager.
See the server log for details.
```

What do I have do to do solve this issue or what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows operating system, Call `%CATALINA_HOME%` is directory what Apache Tomcat installed. (In Unix, macOS, `$CATALINA_HOME` is the home directory of Apache Tomcat)

Looking for file `%CATALINE_HOME%\conf\tomcat-users.xml`. Declare user and corresponding role follow instructor

```
<role rolename="tomcat"/>
<role rolename="role1"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="<must-be-changed>" roles="tomcat"/>
<user username="both" password="<must-be-changed>" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
<user username="role1" password="<must-be-changed>" roles="role1"/>
```

This is an example, it just work

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-status"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui,manager-status,manager-script,manager-jmx"/>
<user username="admin2" password="admin2" roles="manager-gui,manager-status"/>
<user username="admin3" password="<must-be-changed>" roles="manager-jmx"/>
```

You need restart Apache Tomcat for new configuration in affected.

Reference: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring_Manager_Application_Access

Comment: So which credential I have to  input to access the server ? Because a request  for both  username and password is popup when I lunch it .  I have tried but I still don t have access . I am lunching it through  netBeans IDE.

Comment: Ok, I know this situation (Tomcat & Netbeans). Follow my instruction as the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help .credential issue has been tackled thanks for that.But another issue raised because the current web directory is my default  tomcat server one.  THEN I changed the folder to point to my netBEANS folder, It works but this is not good practice I think .So how  to make my project run on tomcat  web page folder ?

Comment: I think the behavior of Netbeans require Tomcat password is unreasonable. Seemly you want ask me something, but I don't clear.

Comment: thus used first three lines as below, thnaks

Comment: <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-status"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui,manager-status,manager-script,manager-jmx"/>

Answer (score 1):

This can be resolve by changing/ammending the below entry in your tomcat directory, in file \conf\tomcat-users.xml

```
<role rolename="manager"/>
  <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager"/>
```

Hope this will resolve your issue